# Opposite of a funnel

Tags: antonyms

A funnel is used for pouring something in it such that it can be going out slower/more controlled. From to broad to narrow.

I'm looking for the opposite of the thing "funnel".

Mostly in the context of an app that would take a single signal and spread it out really broadly.

The closest I got was a "broadcast", but that's not really an object.

Comment: Consider "[megaphone](http://planyourmeetings.com/wp-content/uploads/Man-Megaphone-3.gif)".

Comment: *Lennuf*, would be my guess.

Comment: How about a ***(spray) nozzle***

Comment: @Drew That did cross my mind as well.

Comment: Wouldn't _broadcaster_ work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Distributor
>   Dispenser
>   Disseminator

Comment: also sprinkler [head].

Comment: I would lean toward _distributor_ or _broadcaster_...

Answer (score 1):

Where the hitherto confined stream of a river branches out into many outflows that fan out into the sea, that is called a ***[delta](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/delta)***.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few words fitting different contexts: "nozzle", "horn", "diffusor", "spreader", "expansion", "opening".  As you state

> Mostly in the context of an app that would take a single signal and spread it out really broadly.

you might want to go for something like "diseminator", "multiplier", "distributor", "amplifier".